# SqlAlchemy look-ahead caching?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Edit: Main Topic:
**Is there a way I can force SqlAlchemy to pre-populate the session as far as it can?** Syncronize as much state from the database as possible (there will be no DB updates at this point).

I am having some mild performance issues and I believe I have traced it to SqlAlchemy. I'm sure there are changes in my declarative and db-schema that could improve time, but that is not what I am asking about here.

My SqlAlchemy declarative defines 8 classes, my database has 11 tables with only 7 of them holding my *real* data, and total my database has 800 records (all Integers and UnicodeText). My database engine is sqlite and the actual size is currently 242Kb.

Really, the number of entities is quite small, but many of the table relationships have recursive behavior (5-6 levels deep). My problem starts with the wonderful automagic that SA does for me, and my reluctance to properly extract the data with my own python classes.

I have ORM attribute access scattered across all kinds of iterators, recursive evaluators, right up to my file I/O streams. The access on these attributes is largely non-linear, and ever time I do a lookup, my callstack disappears into SqlAlchemy for quite some time, and I am getting lots of singleton queries.

I am using mostly default SA settings (python 2.7.2, sqlalchemy 0.7).

Considering that RAM is not an issue, and that my database is so small (for the time being), is there a way I can just force SqlAlchemy to pre-populate the session as far as it can. I am hoping that if I just load the raw data into memory, then the most I will have to do is chase a few joins dynamically (almost all queries are pretty straighforward).

I am hoping for a 5 minute fix so I can run some reports ASAP. My next month of TODO is likely going to be full of direct table queries and tighter business logic that can pipeline tuples.

Comment: Your question is overly verbose, what exactly is your question?

Comment: It sounds like you want to use SqlAlchemy like a database and not like an ORM.

Comment: I can't just query the tables (or actually, would that work for what I want?), its the ORM bit that I am hung up on. I have lots of polymorphism and relationships that I depend on.

Comment: I am basically trying to find a quick workaround until I can properly address my overall poor design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A five minute fix for that kind of issue is unlikely, but for many-to-one "singleton" gets there is a simple recipe I use often.  Suppose you're loading lots of `User` objects and they all have many-to-one references to a `Category` of some kind:

```
# load all categories, then hold onto them
categories = Session.query(Category).all()

for user in Session.query(User):
    print user, user.category  # no SQL will be emitted for the Category
```

this because the `query.get()` that a many-to-one emits will look in the local identity map for the primary key first.

If you're looking for more caching than that (and have a bit more than five minutes to spare), the same concept can be expanded to also cache the results of SELECT statements in a way that the cache is associated only with the current Session - check out the [local_session_caching.py](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/examples.html#dogpile-caching) recipe included with the distribution examples.

Comment: Is there any need to actually attempt attribute access once I have query results? If I query tables directly, are those column values held in memory for use on ORM query?

Comment: when Query emits a SELECT, it always emits it, and always fetches all the rows - then most DBAPIs will end up having all the columns fetched within those rows even if they aren't read.   It then matches those rows up to objects already loaded in the Session, and discards those for which there's already an object.   So unless you're doing query caching as in that example, querying always emits SQL, except for that one case where query.get() is used and the identity is already present.

Comment: I did not mention originally that parts of my declarative were defined using Elixir (I am in the process of migrating), and perhaps that was creating some of my problems. Performing the query in the form you suggested definitely helped.